# Extjs form should look like a table

Tags: extjs

i want to create  a form in extjs which can have a combobox, checkbox etc.but it should look like it is inside a grid or a table. I can use property grid, but it would become complicated for my application.

```
fieldName   combobox
fieldName   checkbox
fieldName   combobox
fieldName   textfield
```

Also, I want all the even rows with a particular background color and all odd rows with some other background color. How can I achieve this. thanks

Comment: so it should look like a property grid, but should not be one? a simple column layout is not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your second question with the colors:

add the `cls: y-field-striped` property to every field, this will add a css class to each row.

now with some custom css:

```
.y-field-striped:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #eee } /* even */
.y-field-striped:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color: #aaa } /* odd */
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/8CJ7n/

Comment: yes,i want it to look like a property grid.Is this possible with table layout? i tried this but only one background color was getting applied and that too some white space is left at the right hand side.May be i went wrong somewhere.Can you post a sample example which could help me..thanks

Comment: linked an example which answers your second question, it has nothing to do with your first question

Comment: @user3259903 and I would like to advise you that it would be a good habit if you look at your other open questions and accept an answer if it was helpful, so other users with the same problem can see this.

Comment: sure,i would do that.Can you just help me to know ,how to accept an answer...thanks

Comment: You need to click on the hook under the downvote arrow

Comment: Just wanted to know if i could reduce the width of the textfield in the above example

Comment: thanks.This looks good.Can we cover the white space on the right hand side of the textfield with the grey stripe?